# Inserting Time Date into Google Sheets produces Numero sign №

Tags: google-sheets, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to use the shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> to insert current date and time with Google Sheets on Chrome on MacOS Sierra.

However, this produces the Numero sign `№`.

I have searched the system (Keyboard shortcuts) and cannot find anywhere to prevent this happening.

Note this does work with Firefox so it may be a Chrome issue.

Comment: it is set to override browser shortcuts and that there is no ⌽sign showing that that is a conflict with the browser.